# How can I merge two clips into one split view using iMovie?

Tags: macos, video, imovie, video-editing

What I'd like to achieve is to merge two-screen recordings into one, each one takes half of the screen, using only one of the audio.

An example is this one:

[image]

Two recordings were joined into one on a split screen, and only one audio is played for the final video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iMovie 10 and above:

> 1. Drag and drop the clips that you want to show at the same time to the timeline and make sure one is above another in the timeline.
> 2. Click the Video Overlay Settings icon above the Viewer window and then select Split Screen option from the drop-down box.
>
> [image]

https://filmora.wondershare.com/imovie/split-screen-in-imovie.html

---

> Select a clip or range that you want to show at the same time as
> another clip, and drag it above a clip in the timeline.
>
> When you see the green Add icon (+), release the mouse button.
>
> If the video overlay controls aren’t shown, click the Video Overlay
> Settings button.
>
> Click the pop-up menu on the left and choose Split Screen.
>
> The split-screen controls appear above the viewer, and cropped
> versions of both clips appear in the viewer.
>
> To change when the split-screen effect appears, drag the split-screen
> clip in the timeline so that it connects to a different spot in the
> clip below, or drag it to a different clip. You can also drag the ends
> to lengthen or shorten it.
>
> To apply the change, click the Apply button  in the split-screen
> controls.

https://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.1/#/movb8c659f55

As for selecting the audio from the two clips, you need to detach the audio from the video and adjust their locations on timeline.

- In the timeline, select a video of interest
- Choose Modify > Detach Audio (or press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

Now it behaves just like any other block that you can move, overlap, trim etc.

https://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.1/#/mov267936bb2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Somehow it's not working in my iMovie (10.1.14), should I try to uninstall and reinstall it?

Comment: I've followed the steps you listed here, but the two clips just don't split one my viewer as expected, both of them are in .mp4 format. I know it used to work for still pictures in .png format, now even split screen feature doesn't work for .png format, I think something is wrong here...

Comment: Can you add your iMovie and macOS versions to the question, and see if an update is available. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id408981434 see version history for some fixes if any.

Comment: ok, mine is already the latest version available, and I've checked it on my other Mac which does work as you suggested, i'll accept the answer and figure that out in a different thread, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add info here as to how to choose to combine (or not) the two incoming audio streams?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft done. Thanks for reminding.. I didn't see that it was asked in the question.

Comment: @ankil it wasn't asked, but I was interested.  Thanks!